# How to set up remote repository for a fork?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-fork

I want to fork https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git and orginise work for my team members with my fork so that they could easily rebase against fresh commits from oringinal repository.

I create bare repository on my_remote_server `git init --bare google-api-php-client.git`

Then localy i get clone from original server `git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git`

Then i add to it new remote pointing to my_remote_server `git remote add me my_remote_server:/path/google-api-php-client.git`

Then fill my remote repo with `git push me HEAD`
So by now i have my own repo on my_remote_server with forked google_api. OK. 
Let's say time passed and we pushed many commits into my fork and now one of my team members want to fetch new commits from origin repository of google api and rebase against them. How could be this done?

Answer (score 0):

Very easily:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Or, to do it one step at a time,

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: No, you didn't get the point. Read carefully - `origin/master` contains my fork. But the goal is the to be able to rebase my fork against original upstream just after repository is cloned. So my team member could do something like this 1. clone my fork  2. then fetch new updates from ORIGINAL (not origin) repositry 3. and then rebase origin/master against updates from ORIGINAL (not origin) repositry.

Comment: @notnull: Then just replace `origin` with the upstream remote, then push if you want to.

Comment: Then how would `upstream` appear?

Comment: @notnull: `git remote add`? I'm not sure what your question is.